# Why doesn't directory.io list addresses starting with 3?

Tags: address

Why doesn't directory.io list addresses starting with 3? I have no idea why it is so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directory.io is a joke ([see FAQ](http://directory.io/faq)), or rather an illustration of just how vast the Bitcoin address space is.

It just shows standard P2PKH addresses, which don't include addresses starting with 3.